# How to control edge wear for only certain edges?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, edges, shader-nodes

I'm following along with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnlaIizA_AQ&t=552s

He uses nodes to get the edge wear effect, but how do I achieve more control over this? Such as edge wearing only certain edges.

Is there a way to use vertex groups instead of a shader that auto detects edges? Or use the bevel shader and use a vertex group to control the influence.

Comment: I guess painting a b&w mask will be the best. There are some other ways like Ambiant Occlusion or Pointiness but you  won't get as much control as with an image texture

Answer (score 0):

Just create two materials.

As with all materials you can select the vertices on your object where you want to put your material on and the hit "assign".

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: That's going to create some hard transitions. I would like to have one edge worn and then fade out  towards the adjacent edges.